# What is the name of the system Chronicles of Darkness 2e uses?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, chronicles-of-darkness-2e, chronicles-of-darkness

Going by this [meta post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6218/2788) (I can't find a better main site question): the original/classic World of Darkness uses a system called the *storyteller* system, and Chronicles of Darkness 1e uses the *storytelling* system. By elimination Chronicles of Darkness 2e uses ... neither?

Unless I'm mistaken, CoD 2e is the result of applying the *God-Machine Chronicle Rules Update* to what *was* the CoD 1e/storytelling system, but inferring from our tags (and the later core rules book released), it implies the system used for CoD 2e is not the same as the storytelling system (and thus should not be referred to as such)? It's also confusing that a [*revised* Storytelling System Rulebook](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Chronicles_of_Darkness:_Revised_Storytelling_System_Rulebook) exists, implying that it does use the storytelling system?

If I want to refer to the rules that underpin the books listed under CoD *2e* unambiguously without referencing CoD *1e* and the rules update, especially to people not on RPG StackExchange who use our tags, what should I call that system that underpins CoD 2e?

Comment: I got very confused writing this question, so any feedback is welcomed.

Comment: I've given this a revision because some of the tags referenced didn't exist as such, and I think it's clearer to use natural language here than the specific tags we've got.

Comment: @doppelgreener I'm finding it much harder to read now, but it might be easier to read for somebody else?

Comment: I agree with doppelgreener. In general, I don't think tags should be used inline in mainsite questions; it's better just write your question in natural language instead. Though I'd capitalize the names of the systems (e.g. the Storyteller System and the Storytelling System), as I think that is the proper formatting for them and helps to set them apart from the other text.

Comment: "*If I want to refer to the rules that underpin the books listed under CoD 2e unambiguously*" to be quite honest with you, I feel like you're introducing *more* ambiguity by trying to use the system name. I feel like I have a good amount of experience talking about WoD games and RPGs in general and I can count the times "storytell- -er/-ing system" has been mentioned on the fingers of my hands. It's not really something that comes up often in discussions. Nor does it really help because WW decided to use *almost the same names* for both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [this wiki entry](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Storytelling_System#Revised_Storytelling_System), CoD 2e's revisions are known as the Revised Storytelling System (not to be confused with the [Revised Storyteller System](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Storyteller_System)). It is even how Onyx Path refer to it in [the announcement for the CoD 2e corebook](http://theonyxpath.com/now-available-chronicles-of-darkness/).